# The newest post of each member php mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have a post and 3 members a, b, c. I would like to get the latest post by each member.
I used the query statement

```
$list_user='a,b,c';
mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT post_id FROM post WHERE user IN ($list_user) GROUP BY user ORDER BY post_id DESC");
```

But the results are not what I expected! How do I edit the query so that I can get the latest posts from the 3 members?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need quotes on strings in SQL queries.
Use this instead:

```
$list_user='"a","b","c"';
```

To get the latest post of each member, you don't need the ORDER BY clause.
You need to use MAX() instead.

```
mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT MAX(post_id) FROM post WHERE user IN ($list_user) GROUP BY user");
```

Comment: My query is still working! Only that it can not get the latest posts of those 3 members. It gets the oldest post.